# SOLVED: Soft Power On SIM900 module - JP pads missing!

Tags: hardware

I have this SIM900 board and working just fine.
But i can't find a way to soft power on this board from arduino.
I read for JP pads. They need soldering first, but from my board this JP pads missing.
Know someone other way to soft power on this from arduino?
[image]

Comment: Dielatin... Winner, Winner, Chicken Dinner!! Works a treat, been trying to figure this one out for sometime and there is nothing on the web about it!! So thanks for the solution upload!!

Answer (score 1):

OK for anyone who has the same problem. I solved this by soldering a cable on the underside of the board on this pin (see image) on power button. Then I connect the cable to pin 9 on Arduino and run this on sketch:

```
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT); 
  digitalWrite(9,LOW);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
  delay(2000);
  pinMode(9, INPUT);
```

I don't know how it works, but it solves my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Near C6 and J15 you have 2 points.  You need to solder it.
Before soldering yon can hold wire on one of it (down pin , during code execution).

[image: 1]]